# Change starting column header and read the next row while reading multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnheader

I will like the 'name' row to be the starting column header for all the files. After column header is done, I want the data to start after the it.

I have 3 files (+ more) and the columns are in different index:

```
    2        3      4      5      6       7     ...    
0    A        B     nan    nan    nan     nan    ...     
1    Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     
2    Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     
3    AA       B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     
4    Name  Address  Type   Size   Comment Grade  ...     Brand
5    John    ggg    sports  8     Nil      A     ....    Nike
6    John    ggg    sports  9     Nil      B     ....    Nike
7    Mary    ggg    sports  6     Nil      A     ....    Adidas
```

---

```
     2        3      4      5      6       7     ...    
0    A        B     nan    nan    nan     nan    ...     
1    Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...      
2    Name  Address  Type   Size   Comment Grade  ...     Brand
3    Jack    aaa    sports  10     Nil      A     ....    Nike
4    Jack    aaa    sports  10    Nil      B     ....    Nike
5    May     aaa    sports  6     Nil      A     ....    Adidas
```

---

```
     2        3      4      5      6       7     ...    
0    A        B     nan    nan    nan     nan    ...     
1    Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...     
2    Nan      B     nan    nan     C      nan    ...      
3    Name  Address  Type   Size   Comment Grade  ...     Brand
4    Gary    ddd    sports  10     Nil      A     ....    Nike
5    Gary    ddd    sports  10     Nil      B     ....    Nike
6    Gary    ddd    sports  10     Nil      A     ....    Adidas
```

I was thinking of doing this: (Error)

```
1. a = df.columns.str.startswith('Name')
   df.columns = a
2. a = df.loc['Name']
   df.columns = a
```

I will like to put the code inside here: (Forgot to include this, sorry!!!)

```
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0)
    <Codes to change starting column header>
```

Comment: Question not clear. What is the expected output?

Comment: To change the starting column header from index 0 to row 'Name'

Comment: So, you want to remove the rows before the row which contains 'Name' from the `df'` ?

Comment: Yes, i am open to any solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
loc = df['2'].str.contains('Name').idxmax() # We find the row which has the string 'Name' in column '2'
cols = df.iloc[loc].tolist() #we get the contents of that row to use later as column names
df1 = df.iloc[loc+1:,] #we filter the dataframe to get rows after the row with 'Name'
df1.columns= cols #rename columns
print(df1)
```

**Input**

```
2   3   4   5   6   7   ...     Brand
0   A   B   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     nike
1   Nan     B   NaN     NaN     C   NaN     ...     nike
2   Nan     B   NaN     NaN     C   NaN     ...     nike
3   AA  B   NaN     NaN     C   NaN     ...     Adidas
4   Name    Address     Type    Size    Comment     Grade   ...     Adidas
5   John    ggg     sports  8   Nil     A   ....    Adidas
```

**Output**

```
Name    Address     Type    Size    Comment     Grade   ...     Adidas
5   John    ggg     sports  8   Nil     A   ....    Adidas
```

you `for` loop can be as below

```
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0)
    loc = df['2'].str.contains('Name').idxmax() # We find the row which has the string 'Name' in column '2'
    cols = df.iloc[loc].tolist() #we get the contents of that row to use later as column names
    df1 = df.iloc[loc+1:,] #we filter the dataframe to get rows after the row with 'Name'
    df.append(df1)
```

After you are out of the for loop, you can do `df.columns= cols`

Comment: The first 2 files got replaced by the last file. Even though the format is correct, only the last file is displayed when I exported it. I have edited the body, which include the loop, may i know how not to get it replaced?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
a = df.columns.str.startswith('Name')
```

*df.columns* would be [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], because those are your column names. so that is wrong.Currently *Name* is not in column headers, it is just a value in a column called '2'
instead you can do:

```
a = df[df['2'].str.startswith('Name', na=False)] 
df.columns = a.tolist()
#you should be sure you only have exactly 1 occurrence of 'Name'
```

after setting the columns with the desired names you should delete the row with those names like this:

```
df = df.drop(df['2'].str.startswith('Name', na=False).index)
```

So you need to run *startswith* on the column called '2' (that creates a boolean mask)
in your code 2. you have a similar issue, .loc is used to select data based on labels but currently 'Name' is not column or index label, it is just a value.

It may be helpful if you read up on columns and indexes on pandas and using conditionals to create boolean masks, there are many, I found one nice link: [pandas basics](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-indexing-in-pandas/)

Comment: I got the error at his line : a = df[df['2'].str.startswith('Name')]        Cannot index with vector containing na/nan values.

Comment: see updated code I added **, na=False** to fill the missing values with False. Some rows in df['2'] are missing, that produces an error.